# how to save recorded file with custome file name in android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

```
when user click on stop recording button open popup and ask for file name enter file name then save to sdcard.right now i don't how to do it below my code..please guys help
```

in this code define 4 buttons and xml file when user click on start button start recording when user click on stop button stop record then similar for play and stop play button
but question is how to save particular audio file with specific name

```
Audio.java
public class HomeAdminfgt extends Fragment {
    private MediaRecorder myRecorder;
    private MediaPlayer myPlayer;
    private String outputFile = null;
    private Button startBtn;
    private Button stopBtn;
    private Button playBtn;
    private Button stopPlayBtn, Showaudio;
    private TextView text;
    private ImageView mic_image;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;
    TextView timervalue;
    File file;
    private String[] FilePathStrings;
    private String[] FileNameStrings;
    private File[] listFile;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static String AudioUrl = "http://1biz.in/voice-call/voice.php?method=voiceCall";
    public static String voice_extra = "voice-call";
    public static String voice_string = "recording";

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_adminfgt, container, false);
        Showaudio = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.showaudio);
//        Showaudio.setOnClickListener();
        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Locate the image folder in your SD Card
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "Amuwa");
            // Create a new folder if no folder named SDImageTutorial exist
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        //File file = new File(dir, "recordvoice");
        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        mic_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.micImage);
      //  timervalue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timerValue);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(date.getTime());
        outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                getAbsolutePath() + "/Amuwa/" + "AUD_" + timeStamp + ".wav";

        myRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        myRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        myRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
        startBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                start(v);
            }
        });

        stopBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stop(v);
            }
        });

        playBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.play);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                play(v);
            }
        });

        stopPlayBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.stopPlay);
        stopPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stopPlay(v);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }





    public void start(View view)
    {
        try
        {
            myRecorder.prepare();
            myRecorder.start();
         //   startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
           // customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
            Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha
            animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second
            animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation
            animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // Reverse animation at

            mic_image.startAnimation(animation);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            // start:it is called before prepare()
            // prepare: it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat()
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // prepare() fails
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        text.setText("Recording Point: Recording");
        startBtn.setEnabled(false);
        stopBtn.setEnabled(true);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Start recording...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void stop(View view)
    {
        try
        {

            myRecorder.stop();
            myRecorder.reset();
            myRecorder.release();
            stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            playBtn.setEnabled(true);
            myRecorder  = null;

            mic_image.clearAnimation();
            text.setText("Recording Point: Stop recording");

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Stop recording...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            //  it is called before start()
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // no valid audio/video data has been received
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play(View view)
    {
        try{
            myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            myPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
            myPlayer.prepare();
            myPlayer.start();

            playBtn.setEnabled(false);
            stopPlayBtn.setEnabled(true);
            text.setText("Recording Point: Playing");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Start play the recording...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopPlay(View view)
    {

        try
        {
            if (myPlayer != null)
            {

                myPlayer.stop();
                myPlayer.release();
                myPlayer = null;
                playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                stopPlayBtn.setEnabled(false);
                text.setText("Recording Point: Stop playing");

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Stop playing the recording...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When can create one method to save the file with user's name provided. Call that method when user presses stop button. Below is sample code:

```
private void saveRecording() {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.set_file_name_dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);
    Button cancel = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.save_cancel);
    Button ok = (Button) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.save_ok);


    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false);

    // create alert dialog
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newFileName = userInput.getText().toString();
            if (newFileName != null && newFileName.trim().length() > 0) {
                File newFile = new File(outputFileDir, newFileName);
                File oldFile = new File(outputFileDir, oldFileName);
                oldFile.renameTo(newFile);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

This is the layout file for AlertDialog :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter file name : "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_ok"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but know this code but thing is where put this method to give name to audio clip

Comment: i want implement audio recording function in android means record audio save with user given name

Comment: put this function in your "HomeAdminfgt" class and call it from stop(View view) method